# reading in text file as string list in python

Tags: python, text-files

I have a textfile that looks like:

```
71456137\n
69873481\n
71015205\n
77620788\n
69782796\n
71307244\n
68843955\n
74431739\n
68162271\n
77464886\n
71281027\n
100055063\n
68637778\n
2484\n
```

I want to read it in in python as a list of strings. I want to ask which is the 4th entry Like:

```py
a = open('mytextfile.txt')
print(a[4])
>>> 69782796
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to insert the strings in the text file in to an array d eliminated with newline character. like below

```
a = open('mytextfile.txt')
b=a.split('\n')) 
array=[]
for texts in b:
    array=array.add(text)
```

then you can get your favorite string

```
fav=array[4]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = open('mytextfile.txt', 'r').readlines()
```

another solution:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as a:
    print(a.readlines()[1])
```

Comment: Now you can't use `.close` here. Why not use `with open(...)`.

Comment: `str.split()` splits on all whitespace characters, not only newlines. Also, files already have a `.readlines()` method, and are iterables too so `list(yourfile)` would work too.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('mytextfile.txt') as f:
    a = [line.strip() for line in f.read().split('\\n')]

print(a[4])
```

Comment: The \ in \n gets escaped so it is read in as \\n.